# How can i add a dynamic ip to a MongoDB whitelist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, ip

I have a nodejs application that uses MongoDB as a database. My clients dont want their employees to access the application from anywhere, so i added their ip's to mongodb whitelist so the application can only be used in the specified ips. The problem is that most of my clients have dynamic ip's and i have to change dozens ip's every week so they can access to the app.

What can i do in this case to keep my app secure and prevent users to enter the app from anywhere?

Comment: Why don't you add secuity layer into your app? You can prevent from unauthorized access

Comment: Easiest solution is to use VPN. Whitelisting dynamic IP is a moving target, since the whitelist is only valid for a short amount of time. Another solution is to not allow connection to the database from anywhere, and build a REST API layer (with authentication) on top of the database, so the app uses API calls instead of a straight database calls.

Comment: What do you mean with api calls instead of database calls?